# How can I format a databound textbox as a percentage?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the properties of my textBox, under DataBinding, I can pull up a dialog to set up all kinds of advanced databinding formatting.

I can set there format for numeric currency, dateTime etc but how can I set for percent?

I mean if I have value 1 I would like to present 100 % if 0,5 then 50 % and so on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `P` followed by an optional digit as the format string.

Eg: `Console.WriteLine("{0:P2}", 0.6125)` will print 61.25%.

Comment: well doesnt work in my case :/ it shows for 0.6126: 0.6125:P2 :/

Comment: @gruber: I think for that you just need "P2". (Or maybe "{P2}", can never remember, look at the samples)